Handle screenshot issue, Flutter Windows, ScreenCapturer package
I'm using the ScreenCapturer package in Flutter to capture screenshots on Windows. However, the method _handleClickCapture returns null instead of capturing the screenshot. Here is my code:
void _handleClickCapture(CaptureMode mode, BuildContext context, {
  int displayNumber = 1,
}) async {
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String imageName =
      'Screenshot-${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';
  String imagePath =
      '${directory.path}/screen_capturer_example/Screenshots/$imageName';
  _lastCapturedData = await ScreenCapturer.instance.capture(
    mode: mode,
    imagePath: imagePath,
    silent: true,
  );
  if (_lastCapturedData != null) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    // print(_lastCapturedData!.toJson());
  } else {`your text``your text`
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('User canceled capture');
  }
  setState(() {});
}



I tried setting up the necessary parameters and requirements for the library on Windows. The logs initially return the correct path for the created image, but then I get messages like "Image file does not exist" and other similar logs.
SaveScreenBug--- Captured image path: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\temp_screenshots/Screenshots/Screenshot-1718193689806.png
SaveScreenBug--- Last image path added to CustomStorage
SaveScreenBug--- Capture data: [null, false]
SaveScreenBug--- Captured image path is NULL
